# MIgrations, Atualizando um campo null para not null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, migrations

Estou atualizando o campo phone e CPF da minha entidade User que estava permitindo nulos para não nulos. segue o arquivo de migração

```
public partial class Required_fild_users_cpf_phone : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Users", "CPF", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 11, defaultValue: "00000000000"));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Users", "Phone", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 13, defaultValue: "02932438029"));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Users", "Phone", c => c.String(maxLength: 13));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Users", "CPF", c => c.String(maxLength: 11));
    }
}
```

sendo que o Migrations reclama que minha tabela tem dados e alguns dos registros que tenho que atualizar estão nulos(vazios) então tenho que gerar um arquivo de migração que atualize os campos nulos para um valor padrão para que a migração .não de erros, mas gostaria de fosse no próprio arquivo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione no seu `Up()` um update setando o CPF para vazio quando ele for nulo, mas antes dos `AlterColumn`.

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("update dbo.Users set CPF = '' where CPF is null");
        AlterColumn("dbo.Users", "CPF", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 11, defaultValue: "00000000000"));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Users", "Phone", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 13, defaultValue: "02932438029"));
    }
```

Comment: Também tentei mas de nada funciona, fiz um teste e funciona quando estamos criando o campo. obrigado

Comment: Você poderia colocar na resposta a mensagem do output com o erro que aparece?

Comment: Oi Amigo, deu certo quando fiz uma migração por fez. primeiro o CPF e depois o PHONE.